# Iterate Through Row of a DF Column and change value based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is one column from a Data Frame:

```
Year
1981
1988
-1
1921
2000
-1
```

I need to convert these years (except for rows with -1 in them) into days from 2020.

I have written:
`df['Year'] = 2020 - df['Year']*365`

How do I convert these years into days without considering -1 values. -1 needs to stay the way it is. I need to convert the years only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ddi you want something like?

```
df.loc[df['Year'] != -1, 'Year'] = (2020-df.loc[df['Year'] != -1, 'Year'])*365
```

Output:

```
    Year
0  14235
1  11680
2     -1
3  36135
4   7300
5     -1
```

Another way:

```
df = df.assign(Year=((2020-df.loc[df['Year'] != -1])*365)).fillna(-1)
df
```

Output:

```
      Year
0  14235.0
1  11680.0
2     -1.0
3  36135.0
4   7300.0
5     -1.0
```

Third way:

```
df['Year'] = ((2020 - df['Year'])*365).mask(df['Year']==-1, -1)
```

Output:

```
    Year
0  14235
1  11680
2     -1
3  36135
4   7300
5     -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
import numpy as np
df['Year'] = np.where(df.Year != -1, (2020 - df.Year) * 365, -1)
print(df)
```

Output

```
    Year
0  14235
1  11680
2     -1
3  36135
4   7300
5     -1
```